# Files opening at the beginning of a doc not where last saved

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

When I open any Word file, the file always opens at the beginning of the document.

I work on a extremely large Word document daily and I need the document to open where I last saved the file and not at the top, is there anyway I can stop this?

Cheers Kim

Answer (score 0):

#### I need the document to open where I last saved the file and not at the top

When you open the document press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>.

> If the combination is pressed once it will bring your cursor back to the last position. If pressed multiple times it will scroll through the last few known positions.

Source [Microsoft Word Tip: Continue Editing a Document from Last Cursor Save Position](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/word-2013-restore-cursor-position/)

> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> - Go to a the last change or revision.
>   Also works after opening document.

Source [Word 2013 Shortcuts](https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Word_2013.html)